# Restcomm - JBoss 5 Compatibility

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, restcomm, mobicents

There is a project we've been working on and we use JBoss 5 in it. Recently we wanted to use Restcomm in our project as well but JBoss versions seemed to be a problem. We work with JBoss 5 but from what I understand Restcomm started with JBoss 7 and moved on from there. My question is, is there a way to use Restcomm with JBoss 5, because upgrading from JBoss 5 means a lof of work fork us?

Comment: Unless you're under ELS, this work should be done anyway, JBoss EAP 5 is [out of support](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2739901) and new vulnerabilities won't be fixed. This is a serious security issue. Edit : wait, EAP or AS?

Comment: Valid point, but unfortunately right now that is not an option. Still, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Not exactly sure but I suppose it is AS.

Comment: AS is community version (now named wildfly), EAP is RedHat's supported version. There's no question of support for AS and I don't know exactly how it works, but I'm pretty sure there must not be any new security fixes published for such an old version. More on your topic, I doubt this is possible : while I can't be sure, it's very probably that such a framework would leverage the capacities of the newest JavaEE version, which you won't be able to bring to your older application server

Comment: I realize it's a bit far-fetched, but I wanted to give it shot anyway. You know, what is there to lose. Thanks though.

Comment: Can I suggest realizing a migration POC? It may not be as much work as you fear. Start by checking which framework you're using, and whether they have newer versions supported by recent application servers. Then check their migration guides, as well as JBoss'. Then migrate a few typical processes from JBoss 5.x to 7.x and document the changes needed and the time they take. You might find out it's easier than you'd have thought. Of course guaranteeing it will all still work the same after would require a solid integration test suite or extensive QA, which often is the problem

Comment: Well, the project is a bit massive I'm afraid, so such a renovation in this scale would require really much work, but your ideas are really illuminating. Please, keep them coming.

Comment: By the way I learned that it is AS, release: 5.1.0.GA

Comment: It surely depends on your architecture, but maybe you could not migrate everything all at once : install the new services requiring Restcomm on a new 7.x server, make the 5.x communicate with them. Then when you need to update an old service that exists on the 5.x server, see if you can easily bring it up to date with the 7.x server at the same time, and if you can take the opportunity to migrate it